# Moving an image to a specific spot on page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a specific way to move an image (just an image, not background) to a certain spot when you scroll. So say I load a page, the page loads then an image slides to the left of the page and when you scroll, the image slides to the middle or bottom or where ever you want when you start scrolling the page. And the image stays they there by a set of texts or info. I have tried many things such as:

```
stop().animate({"top":(window.scrollY)
```

I cannot get it to stay there at the spot when scrolling to that specific spot, if you keep scrolling down, the image continues to scroll down when I scroll, and I am not sure how to stop the image after a certain point.

Then I tried this:

```
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
 var a = $(window).height() - 100;
 $('#scrolling').animate({
```

However, I cannot get it to work, it doesn't go back up to top when scrolling back to the top.

Any thoughts on how I would get the image to float in to the center or top or even on the sides and then move to a spot when scrolling down? Am I on the right path or am I totally going about this incorrectly? It feels like I am missing something here, and I am not sure what it is.

I thought I could do this in HMTL5 with animation protocols, but I do not think I can acheive that, and I know CSS3 is robust, but it is also very choppy, so I think JQuery or JavaScript is the way to go, and I can get it partially working but not fully. Any thoughts?

I have searched this site and I cannot find what I am looking for. These are the sites I have found that are similar: [Animated Scroll Image to a particular position on a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261467/animated-scroll-image-to-a-particular-position-on-a-window) and this: [How to make an element fake position:fixed so it acts fixed until a certain scroll height, then attaches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505151/how-to-make-an-element-fake-positionfixed-so-it-acts-fixed-until-a-certain-scro)

But I need an image to move to a spot. Are these links in the right direction? Are the example codes I gave somewhere to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Skroller](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/), it is a JS library (not jQuery dependant, it needs require js though) that allows you to define certain actions.
Basicly you add some data elements to a div, one that says at what pixel (of scrolling) it should start animating, when it stops, and what it does (goes to the middle of screen for example) dsuring that scroll.

Scrolling back up works well (used it in a project of ours)